# Two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am working on a little program to calculate and draw a parabola. But I'm stuck at a little part in the program where I need to calculate the valuetable.

The quadratic function is the following one: `y = a * (x - alpha)² + Beta`.

So if I fill in the following values for this function: `y = 2 * (x - 1)² + (-12)`. I need to become this value table:

> x | -4.0 | -3.0 | -2.0 | -1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
>
> y | 38.0 | 20.0 |  6.0 | -4.0 |-10.0|-12.0|-10.0|-4.0 | 6.0 |

I managed to get the first row right, but the second row (the one that calculates te values), is totally wrong.

```
    public double[][] berekenWaardentabel(int input[], int AANTALKOLOMMEN, double startWaarde) {
    double[][] waarden = new double[RIJEN][AANTALKOLOMMEN];

    System.out.println(waarden.length);
    System.out.println(startWaarde + "\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < RIJEN; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < AANTALKOLOMMEN; j++) {
            waarden[0][j] = startWaarde++; //value of first row (start from -4.0, counts upwards) 
            waarden[1][j] = input[0] * (Math.pow((startWaarde - input[1]), 2)) + input[2];
            System.out.print(waarden[i][j] + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return waarden;
}
```

This is the output I get:

> -4.0                         -3.0  -2.0  -1.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
>
> 86.0  | 116.0 |  150.0 | 188.0  | 230.0  | 276.0  | 326.0  | 380.0  | 438.0  | 500.0  | 566.0

Anyone an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try debugging your code. You should be able to see step-by-step what's happening with the content of your variables.

Comment: startWaarde should be reinitialized to -4 in your 1st loop, otherwise you fill the second row starting with 8 instead of -4.

Comment: I've managed to find the answer to calculate right, but I still have one little problem. The solution of each calculation isn't in the correct order yet. I get ROW1: -4.0 | -3.0 | -2.0 | -1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |    3.0 | 4.0 | 5.0 | 6.0. ROW2: 20.0 | 6.0 | -4.0 | -10.0 |   -12.0  | -10.0 | -4.0 | 6.0 | 20.0 | 38.0 | 60.0. While -4.0 equals 38, and -3.0 is 20. So they need to move 1 to be in the right position.

Comment: You increment startwaarde here: waarden[0][j] = startWaarde++;, you should do it on the next line.

Comment: Okay it works properly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mistakes :

you want to fill two lines of your array (the 0-th (x) and the first(y)). Then you store the value of x in the first row and compute y(x+1) in the second row.

you need to fill your array with :

```
for (int j = 0; j < AANTALKOLOMMEN; j++) {
    waarden[0][j] = startWaarde; // value of first row (start from -4.0, counts upwards)
    waarden[1][j] = input[0] * (Math.pow((startWaarde - input[1]), 2)) + input[2];
    startWaarde++;
}
```

Then you can display your values :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < AANTALKOLOMMEN; j++) {
        System.out.print(waarden[i][j] + "   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First error is this:

```
        waarden[0][j] = startWaarde++; //value of first row (start from -4.0, counts upwards) 
        waarden[1][j] = input[0] * (Math.pow((startWaarde - input[1]), 2)) + input[2];
```

You put the value of `startWaarde` in `waarden[0][j]`. And then you increment it by one.

Then you calculate the value of the function for the *updated* `startWaarde`.

So your `waarden[0][j]` is, perhaps, `4.0`, but you calculate the value `waarden[1][j]` for `5.0` rather than `4.0`.

Your other problem is that you are looping with this line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < RIJEN; i++) {
```

I don't know what the value of RIJEN is. But your `waarden` array is only supposed to have two rows. Once you go through the loop again and again, `startWaarde` keeps growing and growing. Because you print the second row only after this loop iterates the second time, you see the wrong values.

You shouldn't have this loop at all.